# Flatbuffers GoLang- Unable to understand my mistake while serializing and deserializing data resulting in not able to retrieve the data

Tags: go, flatbuffers

I am new to Flatbuffers and GoLang. I am trying to implement a function that take converts an object to flatbuffer and retrieves the same object. Here is my code.
**Updated Code**

```
func getannouncements(){
    annList := SR.GetFromDB().GetAllAnnouncementList()
    fmt.Println(annList)
    builder := flatbuffers.NewBuilder(1024)
    var thisobjlist [12] flatbuffers.UOffsetT
    for i,j := range annList{
        annTitle := builder.CreateString(j.AnnTitle)
        annText := builder.CreateString(j.AnnText)
        annDate := builder.CreateString(j.AnnDate)
        fb.AnnouncementStart(builder)
        fb.AnnouncementAddAnnId(builder,int32(j.AnnID))
        fb.AnnouncementAddAnnTitle(builder,annTitle)
        fb.AnnouncementAddAnnText(builder, annText)
        fb.AnnouncementAddAnnActive(builder,CR.BoolToByte(j.AnnActive))
        fb.AnnouncementAddAnnDate(builder,annDate)
        thisobj:= fb.AnnouncementEnd(builder)
        thisobjlist[i] = thisobj
    }
    fb.AnnouncementListStartAnnListVector(builder,len(annList))
    for _,j:=range thisobjlist{
        builder.PlaceUOffsetT(j)
    }
    finalObj := fb.AnnouncementListEnd(builder)
    builder.Finish(finalObj)
    buf:= builder.FinishedBytes()
    fmt.Println(buf)
    /*bufItem := new(bytes.Buffer)
    binary.Write(bufItem, binary.LittleEndian, buf)
    buf1 := bufItem.Bytes()
    buffyRead := bytes.NewReader(buf1)
    var buffy []byte
    binary.Read(buffyRead, binary.LittleEndian, &buffy)*/
    Anncmt:=  fb.GetRootAsAnnouncementList(buf,0)
    anns := new(fb.Announcement)
    if Anncmt.AnnList(anns,1){
        thisLists := anns.AnnTitle()
        fmt.Println(thisLists)
    }
    fmt.Println(Anncmt)
  }
```

**Schema File**

```
namespace FlatBufs;
table Announcement{
    AnnId:int;
    AnnTitle:string;
    AnnText:string;
    AnnDate:string;
    AnnActive:bool= false;
}

table AnnouncementList{
   AnnName:string;
   AnnList:[Announcement];
}
root_type AnnouncementList
```

The buf object is a byte array. However when I am generating the AnnGot obj I am still getting the almost same byte array as buf. So, When I read various posts on internet on this topic, I tried to convert that buf to binary type and then retrieve buf and tried to retrieve the data (as in the commented part of code). This time the object buffy doesn't have any data in it. I am still not clear what mistake I am making in this entire code.

Please point me in the right direction. Any help on this is much appreciated.

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 0):

Not sure why you're using two builders. Each builder is creating one FlatBuffer, so things you store in one won't be available in the other.

A smaller problem is that you are nesting things (the Go implementation should guard against that, I believe?), i.e. you should finish building all announcements before you create a vector of them.. in your case this will all be mixed up.

You also appear to make your root an `AnnouncementList`, but then you try to access it as an `Announcement`.. this won't work. It be easier to see if we could see your schema.

Comment: if the annlist is large, say 20, I am not sure how can I build all announcements before creating a vector, so I tried creating builder1 to see if that works. Could you please suggest me on how I can build all announcements and create a vector?

Comment: The size of the vector should not matter. Build any number of announcements into the builder, and collect their offsets in a temporary vector of the same size. Then create a FlatBuffers vector from that in the same builder, followed by the root table (that refers to the vector).

Comment: I updated the code as you suggested and schema file in my question. Definitely I am getting a larger flatbuffer with this code after the changes based on your suggestion, however I am still not getting my data back from the buffer. Thanks for answering my questions.